# Javascript ajax and callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I don't realy understand why my variable is undefined
This is my code:

```
Calendar = function() {

    this.data;  
    this.init = function(path, callback){
        $.ajax({
            url:path,
            type:'GET',
            success:function(data){
                this.data = data;
                console.log(this.data);
                callback();
            }
        })
    }

    this.create = function(){
        this.generateYear();
    }   

    this.generateYear = function(){
        console.log(this.data); 
    }   
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.init(path,function(){
        calendar.create();
    });
});
```

So the first console.log is good but the second is undefined, I don't understand why because he is called after.

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @elclanrs Doesn't look like this one, there

Comment: what is `callback();` after first `console.log(this.data);`

Comment: Hi use var k=this.data;in success function k=data; in generateYear = k;

Comment: You're right, my bad, it looked like it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set context param in ajax function. Try this one:

```
 $.ajax({
        url:path,
        type:'GET',
        context: this,
        success:function(data){
            this.data = data;
            console.log(this.data);
            callback();
        }
    })
```

Comment: @MichaelWalter `context`. And it looks like a good answer. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

`this`, in the callback you give to ajax, isn't your calendar.

Change your init function to

```
this.init = function(path, callback){
    var calendar = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:path,
        type:'GET',
        success:function(data){
            calendar.data = data;
            console.log(calendar.data);
            callback();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good answer but I prefer Michael's answer, I find this more proper

Comment: @ant Personally I really prefer to always keep in mind the native closure based solution than to try to remember all the parameters of the `ajax` function. But his answer is good too (I upvoted it) so I won't reproach you to choose it. Simply be sure to understand my answer because it's the solution you'll use in all other similar cases :)

Comment: @ant dystroy answer is more readable .. Michael's answer using `this` will make confusion

Answer (score 0):

Within this.generateYear your call to "this" is not more referencing your Calendar object and is referencing the Window object which most probably doesn't have data as an attribute. Make sure you read more about [Javascript binding](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations)

Storing an instance of this in a variable within your object and later using it, would work. Example:

```
this.init = function(path, callback){
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:path,
        type:'GET',
        success:function(data){
            self.data = data;
            console.log(self.data);
            callback();
        }
    })
}
```